# Draft.js new line after and before IMMUTABLE entity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rte, draftjs

how to get rid of a break after and before every IMMUTABLE object in editor.
When I add image for example.

```
const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
            "image",
            "IMMUTABLE",
            { src: urlValue }
        );
```

I place cursor where the red mark is and add image, I got line break after and before.
[image]

Same with custom entity, I am not abble to even place cursor to the right of the icon (red square), how to fix that?

[image]